# Why there is no high voltage repeater / voltage translator ic (like max232) for I2C

Tags: communication, i2c, wire

why I2C don't work  don't work with long wire, for UART we have 10 volt translators like max232, for I2C why there is no high voltage repeater ic?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this question has a right answer, but the main motivation might be that I2C was conceived as a chip to chip on board communication protocol, and not as a "high distance" communication protocol.

On a PCB having somewhat high voltages lying around is quite a pain, plus each chip should include another voltage rail, and so on. U(S)ART is an RS232 derivative, i.e. it's RS232 with lower voltages, and that's why you can find the MAX232 and similar.

In the past the first difficulty that had to be overcome was "fast" and reliable off board communication, thus RS232 was born. It uses some +-12V I believe, and can go for quite a distance. Chips evolved, prices lowered and suddendly you have 10 chips on a single board, using RS232 is sub optimal because high voltages are not needed, and you'd need a port per chip on the main chip, or some daisy chain, or whatever. And here comes I2C: low voltage, multi device, two lines, faster, and so on.

I believe you can't find many voltages translators for I2C because I2C is not the right thing to use if you need higher voltages.

Comment: I do run I2C off board and even long runs from time to time, but I did so by deriving I2C signals into differential current loops (aka I2C protocol over CAN PHY) so it is not I2C itself cannot be wired off board, but the physical layer of I2C that should not be wired off.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Because it can be done using two MOSFETs and actually NXP do have such chips like [P82B96](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P82B96.pdf).

Comment: Two MOSFETs can be used to do level translation between two busses with different pullup voltages, but they do nothing at all in terms of improving drive capability or noise immunity.